# Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string()

Tags: installation

I have activated my civicrm 5.41.0 but while about to install it, the debug give a fatal error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:1161
 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/UI/SetupController.php(338): CRM_Utils_System::version()
 #1 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/UI/SetupController.php(217): Civi\Setup\UI\SetupController->getCommonTplVars()
 #2 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/UI/SetupController.php(95): Civi\Setup\UI\SetupController->render()
 #3 [internal function]: Civi\Setup\UI\SetupController->runStart()
 #4 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/UI/SetupController.php(65): call_user_func()
 #5 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/BasicRunner.php(21): Civi\Setup\UI\SetupController->run()
 #6 /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php(252): Civi\Setup\BasicRunner::run()
 #7 / in /var/www/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php on line 1161
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your hosting provider doesn't have simplexml installed. Just ask them to enable it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php#122043

Comment: ok thanks you...